# How to set the foreground color of text in NavigationView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to change the colors of the `NavigationView`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#customizing-backgrounds) gives a nice example of how to change the background but I could not find how to change the font color of the menu items. 
I was also able to change the color of selection indicator using `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NavigationView is one of the many controls which automatically use the *Reveal highlight*, which is also one of the new Fluent Design System component, and whose objective is to add light to the application.

@A. Milto solution would work if we were dealing with a control which doesn't share as many states as NavigationViewItem does, however NavigationMenuItem has:

- PointerOver;
- Pressed
- Selected;
- PointerOverSelected;
- PressedSelected;

without taking into account it's disabled states.
Simply forcing the foreground property to your desired Color, will give the following:

[image]

The easiest solution to achieve what you intent is to override the resources in the NavigationViewItem Template, which you can actually check out in the *generic.xaml*. You can do so, like this:

```
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed" Color="Red"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

In case you want the initial state of your NavigationViewItem Content and the Icon to be set to Red, you have to set it out in the markup.

This is the list of items used to populate the *NavigationView.MenuItems*

```
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="AllApps" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"  Content="Apps" Tag="apps"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Video" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" Content="Games" Tag="games" />
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Audio" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Music" Tag="music"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

Result:

[image]

With this implementation *Foreground* is separated from the *Border/Background*, which are the other elements responsible for the characterization of the Reveal feature.

You can modify the resourcers mentioned above to implement your own UI logic, more "beautiful" than the one we are achieving right now, and even use bindings to alter the theme on runtime depending on Custom Themes that you're app might offer.

**EDIT:**
To set the Foreground Property for all NavigationViewMenuItems (**including the Settings**), override the following resource:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForeground" Color="Red"/>
```

With this you don't need to be setting the Foreground explicitly for all the Items. With NavigationView's `SettingsItem` property, i only managed to change the Icon color.

Comment: Does it change the `Setttings` style too?

Comment: I didn't try it, but i wouldn't be surprised if that wasn't the case, since the Settings seems to be an unique menu item. But checking out the generic.xaml, you will much likely get your answer!

Comment: Or it might actually work and i am just spouting nonsense! 
The computer i am using right now is on the Windows 10 Anniversary Update version, so no way to actually test this out.

Comment: As you say settings is special. Maybe it is not a NavigationViewItem, otherwise, it should have changed. I will look into generic.xaml to find a clue.

Comment: Edited the post, with a solution which will also makes possible to set the Foreground Color of the Settings Item!

Comment: I would like to add that, if you change the layout of your navigationView to be on top, you will need to add a "Top" word prefix before each of these words, e.g: "TopNavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver"

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<NavigationView ...>
    ...
    <NavigationView.MenuItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </NavigationView.MenuItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: Only works partially. `Foreground` goes back to default when it is selected. Also, Settings menu item is not impacted by this change.